# A lot of database connections jsp

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, web-applications, mysql-connector

I made a Java Webapp with Spring and Hibernate where I have to take a lot of data from the database, but I have a problem, because the app is too slowly and I need to make it faster. I think that the higher problem is the amount of conexions that I do in each jsp file, and I don't know how to solve it. That conexions I think are all neccesary, but maybe I can modify some part of code to make it faster. I pass the data to the jsp via Hibernate and Spring in the model, but then in the jsp I have to make a connection with the database to take some more information that are in another class. For example, I have some players, and in the player I have the ID of their team, so I have to connect in the jsp to take the name of the team, because I only know the ID. I show you how I connect the app with the database:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
    Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "user", "pwd");
    if (!conexion.isClosed()) {
        // La consulta
        Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM entity");

        while (rs.next()){
            aaa = rs.getObject("aaa").toString();
        }

        // cierre de la conexion
        conexion.close();
    }
    else 
        // Error en la conexion
        out.println("fallo");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Error en algun momento.
    out.println("Excepcion "+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I do this same a lot of times in the same jsp, even 10-15 times in the biggers jsp.
Can I open the conexion in the begin of the jsp and close the conexion in the end and put all the jsp code and html inside the conexion with the database to make only 1 connection?

And another doubt, in the same conection, if I have to do 2 querys, I do like this:

```
        Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM entity");

        while (rs.next()){
            aaa = rs.getObject("aaa").toString();
        }

        st = conexion.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from entity2");

        while (rs.next()){
            bbb = rs.getObject("bbb").toString();
        }
```

So, I create a new Statement for the query, is it neccesary? Or is enough if I create the Statement in the first query? And is this important in the speed of the page?

Does someone know what could I do to make my app faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Database connection code in a JSP? I think my eyes just melted.

Comment: How do you write unit tests against your JSP code? Presumably you have massive "chunks" of code that you copy/paste around? How do you maintain that? And that's just for starters...

Comment: I don't have unit tests. And yes, the code I copy/paste from one connection to the other and I modify the query. But if I don't do this, how I can do? How can I get the data from the database? Because I can't do in the model...

Comment: This sounds like a disaster. Delete it and start again. Maybe read a book on MVC or MVP or _any_ software design principles.

Comment: You will help me or not? I know how to do a MVC, I only want to improve this, I don't want to make one new. And in the case that I make a new app, how should I do? Because you only say that what I made is bad, but not which are the correct way...

Comment: Somebody can help me?

Comment: What server? Tomcat? Jboss? Glassfish? Jetty?

Comment: Tomcat server and mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `Statement st = conexion.createStatement();` is sufficient.  Don't keep recreating the statement. You only have a limited amount of times you can call createStatement. If you need a nested query, make two statements, st and st2, but do not keep calling createStatement for the same variable.

Also, if you are going to use connections in scriptlets, you should at the very least make a class to put the actual connecting part in, i.e. `Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"); Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(....);` and then just call that in the JSP.  That way you don't have messy connection code in every JSP and when you have to change the server IP or username or something you won't have to go change a slew of JSPs.

And don't open the connection 10 times in one JSP. You wouldn't even want to do that in a Servlet.  You would want to create a member variable that is of type `Connection`, open it, and keep it open and until the end.

If you are going to use scriptlets, your code should be at least this clean:

```
<%
//call a static method in a class you create to get the connection
Connection connection = Appname.dbclass.getConnection();
if(connection==null)
{
   out.print("error connecting");
   return;
}
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = null;
...
//do all your stuff
...
if(rs!=null)
{
   try
   {
     rs.close();
   }
   catch(Exception ex){}
}
if(st!=null)
{
   try
   {
     st.close();
   }
   catch(Exception ex){}
}
if(connection!=null)
{
   try
   {
     connection.close();
   }
   catch(Exception ex){}
}
%>
```

Also, instead of doing "select * from table" followed by something like:

```
while (rs.next()){
  aaa = rs.getObject("aaa").toString();
 }
```

use a WHERE CLAUSE in your SQL to limit the number of rows returned to ONE, and also limit the fields you pull to the ones you need ("select aaa from table WHERE id=1") and then an if-statement:

```
  if (rs.next()){
   aaa = rs.getObject("aaa").toString();
  }
```

With your present code, each time you go through the loop again, aaa is being overwritten with a new value.  Its wasting a ton of processing time either doing nothing or ensuring that the result is completely wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't try it this days because I was very busy. I will try it today and tomorrow this code.
I don't understand something of your explanation. You say that I have to make a class to put the actual connect part. Ok, I understand why, and it has sense, and I would like to make this at the beginning but I didn't know that was possible, but my question is, where I have to make that class? And how I can make it? And how can I call it?
PD: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can put it under WEB-INF/classes/YourPackageName/, make sure the code of that class begins with `package YourPackageName;`, and in your JSP you can call it by YourPackageName.className. If you make the method that returns the Connection a static method, you can just call like `YourPackageName.className.methodName();`

Comment: I've already tried this code, and it runs well, thanks! Another question. Why did you say that instead of while, i should use if to take the data from the database? If the query only returns 1 row, the while is like a if, only enter once. But sometimes the query returns more values that I have to save, so I need more than 1 iteraction, so I need a while, not an if. Obviously, I have a where clause in the query, but here I didn't put it because is only an example. Thanks again!

Comment: `while (rs.next()){aaa=rs.getObject("aaa").toString();} out.print(aaa);` How many values will be printed?  Just one. If you really need a loop you need operations in the loop.  A loop with just an *assignment* is a total waste of CPU. If it loops 10 times, 9 values just disappear and nothing is done with them, except they take time.

Comment: Yes, in this case only will be printed the last value of the loop.
But when I want to save all the values I put it into a list, so I save all the values, I am right?
And when I only want 1 value, what's the difference between a while and an if? Both operation only will enter once, right?
I will check all the querys, but I think that in the querys where I want more than 1 value, I put it in a list, and in the rest of the querys, the query only returns one value, so I think it's the same like an if.